# weird when removing decimal in float value

Tags: objective-c

```
NSNumber* n = @(7654321098.345);
float maxTimestampInFloat = [n floatValue];
long groundedMaxTimestamp = lroundf(maxTimestampInFloat);
NSNumber* result = @(groundedMaxTimestamp);
```

the result value become 7654321152, which I expected It should be 7654321098.

I have checked the max of float is:

float max value: 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000

why?

Comment: what is maxTimestamp?

Answer (score 0):

There is small change in your code,

```
   NSNumber* n = @(7654321098.345);
        double maxTimestampInFloat = [n doubleValue];
        long groundedMaxTimestamp = round(maxTimestampInFloat);
        NSNumber* result = @(groundedMaxTimestamp);
```

Use double instead of float. I have checked it from my side and its working fine.

Hope this will help you.